# Date Time format confusion in my SharePoint 2013 server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, date-time, formatting, settings

I want all my date columns in the entire server to be in 'DD/MM/YYYY' format.

So I setup the Locale in the regional settings as 'United Kingdom'. I did the changes in the following locations:

1. Central Admin
   (http://mysharepointserver:port/_layouts/regionalsetng.aspx)
2. Root site regional settings
3. Sub site regional settings

However, when I create a custom list with a Date Only column. The date is displayed as 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

Any idea why this is happening? two weeks back I created a staging server and that has my desired result.

Comment: Is this what you're seeing? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187061/document-library-date-time-gives-invalid-datetime-value-error-after-changing-s?noredirect=1#comment196849_187061

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not overriding the regional settings in user regional preferences.

Steps [here](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2012/11/02/how-to-change-regional-settings-on-my-site-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx).

Comment: How can I check for that? MySite settings?

Comment: http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2012/11/02/how-to-change-regional-settings-on-my-site-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: Looks like I have an issue with the my site, getting a 404 error :( But the sitecollection is accessing... Person.aspx is getting a 404